# Soft or hard pick for funk 16ths?

Tags: electric-guitar, picks

I'm trying to get into funk with my electric guitar and am currently practicing keeping the 16ths rhythm and learn keeping a loose wrist. I usually play with a thick pick ("fender heavy"), but should I use a softer pick for strumming quick 16ths in a funky style?

(Of course I should use whatever feels the best, but I'm a beginner to funk and would like to know the most appropriate/pedagogical approach.)

Comment: I use fender heavy for everything and have never doubted that choice. I like to have the tactile feedback from the strings. It’s more a matter of your personal taste than what genre or style you’re playing.

Answer (score 1):

The usual disclaimers apply here: the tone is in your fingers and not your gear, do what sounds and feels good to you, and there is this one guitarist who plays with a coin and had a disco hit back in the day. On the other hand, thin pick is easy to strum with and produces a lot of overtones to feed into wah or whatever you have.

For what it's worth, [Nile Rodgers plays super soft pick](https://twitter.com/nilerodgers/status/949097572160942081) and it seems to work for him. Picks don't cost much, so might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more to do with how you use it, rather than what it is. Yes, flexible (rather than loose) wrist, litlle tip showing, and more important, how you hold it.

If it's too tightly, it won't 'feather' (just like windscreen wiper blades need to), so the recovery from one direction to the opposite will be impeded. So, as loose as you can, without dropping it. Maybee best to have just one pick, rather than a different one for each style!